# Why would a double pointer be needed? In which example of a situation?

Tags: c, pointers

I have 2 pieces of codes shown below:

The first one is:

```
void input(int * a) {
    (*a) = 10;
}

int main() 
{
    int * a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    input(a);
    printf("%d", *a);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

And the second is:

```
void input(int ** a) {
    *(*a) = 10;
}

int main() 
{
    int * a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    input(&a);
    printf("%d", *a);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I ran those two codes, and they showed the same output (which is 10). I wonder if they had the same meaning? Can you help me to point out the difference (if any)?

Comment: The difference is that you pass an integer pointer in the first case, and a pointer to an integer pointer in the second case.

Comment: I think you question is "Why would a double pointer be needed? In which example of a situation?". Consider rephrasing please. Because for the question as is you will probably get many variations of goodvibrations comment as answers, and I feel that you would not be satisfied.

Comment: You can have as many levels of indirection as you like, but you should limit it to no more than you actually need.  One level is common, two is less common, and three or more is pretty rare and best avoided if possible.  In your example, you only need one level of indirection, so the first version is what you want.  The second version doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you very much! I will modify my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You demonstrated that you understand the need for a pointer to int,
i.e. in cases where the result/effect of a function is expected to be a modification of the int pointed to.

The need for a double pointer arises when the expected effect is a modification of a pointer.
The most popular need for having a pointer modified (or potentially modified) is the insertion, sorting or deletion operation of linked lists. The need to be able to modifiy the pointer which refers to the list (or the first element in the list).

For example StackOverflow has many questions along the lines of "Why does my linked-list deletion only work after the first element?".
About half of the answers propose to return the new head pointer and update it outside of the function. The other half recommends to use a double pointer to allow modifying it (the pointer-to head pointer) inside the function. Both works, it is a matter of taste/habit/opinion which approach to use.

Answer (score 2):

You're ultimately setting it to an `int` value (10), so obviously an `int**` is not really needed in your example.

However, if you needed to set it to an `int*` value, then an `int**` would be needed.

For example:

```
void input(int** a) {
    *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main() 
{
    int* a;
    input(&a);
    printf("%p", a);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```